# consume a webservice using apache httpClient for multipart data on post throws error which accepts gzip encoding.

Tags: java, web-services, gzip, apache-httpcomponents

This is the code that worked for me to consume a webservice say for example **"urn:authe#createEmp"**. Now in the same server when i consume 
 **"urn:authe#createUser"** it throws java.util.zip.ZipException . Following is the program.

```
package pack;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost; 
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

public class WebServiceClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    String url = "http://localhost/ProjectName/WebService.php";

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

    post.setHeader("SOAPAction", "urn:authe#createUser");

    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.addTextBody("firstname", "Siva", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
    builder.addTextBody("lastname", "LASTNAME", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);

    // builder.addBinaryBody("file", new
    // File("..."),ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, "file.ext");

    HttpEntity multipart = builder.build();

    post.setEntity(multipart);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

    System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }

    System.out.println(result.toString());
  } 
}
```

Response from console is:

```
Response Code : 200
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:164)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:78)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:90)
at org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseContentEncoding$1.create(ResponseContentEncoding.java:67)
at org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream.initWrapper(LazyDecompressingInputStream.java:54)
at org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream.read(LazyDecompressingInputStream.java:72)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:154)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:317)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:382)
at pack.WebServiceClient.main(WebServiceClient.java:78)
```

I tried searching for options to encode the request with gzip format. till now got no solution. Help me regarding this.